# How to write input from input box from a flask website into a csv or txt file

Tags: python, flask

I have a basic flask website and I would like to know how to write the input from a basic input box into a csv or txt file. I thought my code would work but all it did was create a blank csv file.
My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import csv
import io


app = Flask(__name__)
f = open('test.csv')
outFile = open('containers.csv', 'w')

free = csv.reader(f)
outFile.write("number" + '\n')


@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['u']
    marker = str(text)
    return "You inputed " + text
    for row in free
        outFile.write(marker + '\n')

    f.close()
    outFile.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Input</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form method="POST">
    <p>Input</p><br>
    <input name='u'>
    <input type='submit'>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the python section but I don't know what's going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a text file, why not define a function like:

```
def write_file(data):
    with open('containers.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(data + '\n')
```

Putting the `open` function within the `with` statement, means the `f` object is available within that block.  The file is also automatically closed when the block finishes.

Then you could have a single view function which handles both rendering the form, and accepting the posted result:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def my_form():
    if request.method=='POST':
        text = request.form['u']
        write_file(text)
        return "You inputed " + text
    elif request.method=="GET":
        return render_template('form.html')
```

You should also add an `action` attribute to the `form` start tag:

```
<form method='POST' action='{{ url_for("my_form") }}'>
```

Now the form will submit to the correct endpoint, even if you change the endpoint which is assigned to the `my_form` function.

Comment: I have a question though. How can I make it so that the txt file is saved? Every time I run the program the txt file restarts.

Comment: @mark See my update to the `write_file` function.  Passing `'a'` as the second arg to `open` causes contents to be appended; also a newline is added to the written string.

Comment: @mark although be aware, this example falls over if several requests come in to the server at once (say a 2nd request hits while the first request is executing and has a lock on the file.  In that case the 2nd request would raise an exception, and the contents wouldn't be written).  The way to mitigate this is to use a different storage backend (not a file).  Also many modern hosting platforms are designed with non persistant disk space, hence the use of a different storage backend; It would depend on your usecase.